# OneDrive like System Tray popup

Tags: python, user-interface, window, system-tray

I would like to create a python app that looks like the OneDrives app: A system tray icon than can be pressed and then opens an interactive popup above the icon. I am wondering if it's a special framework/library or really just a boarderless window at a fixed position.

Thanks

[image: OneDrive Popup]